# Java Hotspot command line parameter to increase the maximum size of Java method

Tags: java, jvm-hotspot

Is there a command line parameter to increase the maximum size of Java method (from 8000 bytecodes) that Hotspot will compile?

Comment: Can you explain more about the context?

Comment: Basically I am writing a cross compiler from other languages and currently the resulting methods are still very bloated (sometimes over 50,000 bytecodes), but I want to get a measure of the speed when hotspot is compiling them, and see what kind of code hotspot outputs for the structures I'm using.

Comment: There's probably not too much useful information that you'll get from the results here. HotSpot likes working with small methods - so trying to do this with large methods may not tell you much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might have to download the [sources](http://download.java.net/jdk6/) and build with debug flags for this (I'm not sure).

`java -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions  -XX:-DontCompileHugeMethods`

More information can be found [here](http://blog.headius.com/2009/01/my-favorite-hotspot-jvm-flags.html).

If you download the sources I think most of the (hundreds) flags can be found..
`hotspot/src/share/vm/runtime/arguments.cpp`

`hotspot/src/share/vm/runtime/globals.cpp`

Comment: Thank you. I'm not looking for the maximum size for a method to be inlined, but the maximum size for a method to be compiled by hotspot, which is 8000 by default. I can't find it in either of those files, but I have a vague memory of such an option existing.

Comment: Ah, sorry I didn't read carefully enough :) good luck hunting for it in the source files :)

Comment: I found it... -XX:-DontCompileHugeMethods

Comment: Also, I don't think you need the -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions